# Connecting a Client to Multiple Servers Simultaneously in JAVA using Sockets

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I want to implement a multi-threaded client socket in JAVA which will connect with multiple servers..
For eg..
The client will accept an array of numbers and split that array into two.. The two arrays will be sent to two servers and the result from the servers will be combined by the client to get the Final sorted array..

Any help guys???

Comment: Yes, good luck. Start writing code and you will probably succeed. If you have any problems ask questions describing the problems.  If you want to hire someone to do the work for you it is another matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's split the "client" meaning in 2:

1. client application, the app which you're creating which will communicate with one or more servers
2. client-socket, a client side of a communication channel, which can be connected to maximum one server at any time

As a side note, only [server-sockets can handle multiple clients "at the same time"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html#later)

Now, you can not have a client-socket connect to multiple servers, but you can have a client application connecting to multiple servers by having an instance of client-socket connect to each server.

So what your client application needs to do, is manage a list of client-sockets that connect to your servers, and upon receiving all the replies, aggregate the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apache hadoop is what you have to use in this scenario.